# Single checkbox to check multiple checkboxes in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, checkbox

Hi good people of stackoverflow, I have created a groupBox1 which contains 39 checkboxes which can be checked individually, and I have created a gropuBox2 which contains single check box called "Check All", What I want is when the "Check All" check box is checked all the 39 checkboxes will be selected and when the "Check All" is unchecked all 39 checkboxes will be unchecked also, Can someone please help? Thank you very much.

Comment: is the 39 checkboxes are located inside any control or they were stand alone in the form?

Comment: Yes, the 39 controls are inside a groupbox1 and the checkAll checkbox is inside groupBox2

Comment: Are there any other checkboxes on the form anywhere?

Comment: Cool Neethu Soman, Thanks it works very good, if I want to the 39 unchecked when the checkAll is checked, I just need to reverse your code bellow? Apologies for this, I should have entered this part on  my initial question.

Comment: You could add another argument to the checkControls method that is a boolean representing the checked state desired.

Comment: Hi Neethu Soman, I've tried to call the function e.g.  "Private Sub checkAll_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkAll.CheckedChanged
        checkControls(GroupBox1, True)
        checkControls(GroupBox1, False)
    End Sub" but when I check the CheckAll checkbox all checkboxes are checking and unchecking at the same time.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH all that Replied, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how *I* would do it. Filter the controls by type using [Enumerable.OfType<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx) then iterate the result using [Array.ForEach<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zecdkyw2(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
Private Sub CheckBoxAll_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckAll.CheckedChanged
    Array.ForEach(Me.GroupBox1.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox).ToArray(), Sub(box As CheckBox) box.Checked = Me.CheckAll.Checked)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

If all your controls are in the form ( not in groupbox/pannel) you can use the following code

```
  Dim chk As CheckBox
  If checkAll.Checked = True Then
     For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
         If TypeOf ctrl Is CheckBox Then
            chk = DirectCast(ctrl, CheckBox)
            chk.Checked = True
         End If
     Next
   End If
```

**Updates as per edit and comment:**

If you want to find controls inside `Groupbox1` means you can do like the following

```
''' <summary>
''' sets CheckBox.Checked inside a container
''' </summary>
''' <param name="parentControl">the container</param>
''' <param name="chkState">ture or false</param>
''' <remarks>use: checkControls(GroupBox1, True)</remarks>
Public Sub checkControls(ByVal parentControl As Control, chkState As Boolean) '<----Pass the parent control where the checkBoxes belongs
    Dim chk As CheckBox = Nothing
    For Each ctrl As Control In parentControl.Controls '<-----Change from the above code
        If TypeOf ctrl Is CheckBox Then
            DirectCast(ctrl, CheckBox).Checked = chkState
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

To check call the function as

```
  checkControls(GroupBox1, True)'<----Since your checkboxes are inside the groupBox1
```

To uncheck call the function as

```
  checkControls(GroupBox1, False)'<----Since your checkboxes are inside the groupBox1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there are **only** 40 checkboxes on the form then this will work

```
    Dim ctrl As Control = Me.GetNextControl(Me, True)
    Do Until ctrl Is Nothing
        If TypeOf ctrl Is CheckBox Then
            DirectCast(ctrl, CheckBox).Checked = True
        End If
        ctrl = Me.GetNextControl(ctrl, True)
    Loop
```

If there are more than 40 checkboxes then take a look at Neethu Soman's solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the code below and works for me but Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå code works much better:

```
Private Sub cbxAll_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cbxAll.CheckedChanged                                                                      
If cbxAll.Checked = True Then
    cbx01.Checked = True
    cbx02.Checked = True
    ' 3 .. 38
    cbx39.Checked = True
Else
    cbx01.Checked = False
    cbx02.Checked = False
    ' 3 .. 38
    cbx39.Checked = False
End If
End Sub
```